# How can I convert PDF files to ePub format?

Tags: pdf, conversion, epub

I have a CD of PDF files, is there a way I can convert them to ePub files?
Is there an online/desktop tool that will allow me to do that?

Comment: unfortunately PDFs dont convert well

Answer (score 3):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) is the way to go for conversion between eReader formats, it's a free cross-platform tools.

Answer (score 2):

As slubman says, Calibre is the best offline tool to do it.

If you want to do it one-off/online, [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) can do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.epub2go.com/Web/default.aspx

you'll have to do them one at a time though

Answer (score 1):

All automated PDF to ePub tools do a bad job, as they have a hard time stripping out page headers and footers and joining up paragraphs that span more than one page.

Comment: Readability/Instapaper/Read It Later wouldn't work either.